# Possible reasons of NoClassDefFoundError in runtime

Tags: java, weblogic

I have `Weblogic 9`, `JRockit` and application running on two nodes of WebLogic.
After application was compiled, deployed and successfuly running for some hours I got following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/concurrent/LockType
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.readLock(FrontEndCacheTier.java:632)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.getKeys(FrontEndCacheTier.java:485)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:1913)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.servermap.OnlineEhcacheSMLocalStore.getKeys(OnlineEhcacheSMLocalStore.java:44)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.servermap.EhcacheSMLocalStore.getKeys(EhcacheSMLocalStore.java:82)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.collections.servermap.L1ServerMapLocalCacheStoreImpl.getKeys(L1ServerMapLocalCacheStoreImpl.java:51)
    at com.tc.object.servermap.localcache.impl.ServerMapLocalCacheImpl.clear(ServerMapLocalCacheImpl.java:247)
    at com.tc.object.TCObjectServerMapImpl.clearLocalCache(TCObjectServerMapImpl.java:600)
    at com.terracotta.toolkit.collections.ConcurrentDistributedServerMapDsoApplicator.hydrate(ConcurrentDistributedServerMapDsoApplicator.java:145)
    at com.tc.object.TCClassImpl.hydrate(TCClassImpl.java:199)
    at com.tc.object.TCObjectImpl.hydrate(TCObjectImpl.java:113)
    at com.tc.object.tx.ClientTransactionManagerImpl.basicApply(ClientTransactionManagerImpl.java:350)
    at com.tc.object.tx.ClientTransactionManagerImpl.apply(ClientTransactionManagerImpl.java:378)
    at com.tc.object.handler.ReceiveTransactionHandler.handleEvent(ReceiveTransactionHandler.java:100)
    at com.tc.async.impl.StageImpl$WorkerThread.run(StageImpl.java:145)  

<04.07.2012 13:28:54 MSD> Notice WebLogicServer BEA-000388 JVM called WLS shutdown hook. The server will force shutdown now  

<04.07.2012 13:28:54 MSD> Alert WebLogicServer BEA-000396 Server shutdown has been requested by WLS Kernel
Exception in thread "Thread-42" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/concurrent/LockType
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.writeLock(FrontEndCacheTier.java:644)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.removeAll(FrontEndCacheTier.java:503)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeAll(Cache.java:2461)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.removeAll(Cache.java:2446)
    at org.terracotta.modules.ehcache.store.servermap.OnlineEhcacheSMLocalStore.clear(OnlineEhcacheSMLocalStore.java:13
```

As you can see WebLogic decided to shutdown both nodes after receiving this error.
What are the reasons of `NoClassDefFoundError` during Runtime? I suppose that this class `LockType` should be used before this error that means it had to be unloaded in runtime, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345963/terracotta-unexpected-commonshutdownhook-and-client-exiting.

Comment: This question is more common. And I hope more people can help me with that. Another post is very specialized, and I'm not sure that terracotta or ehcache make any sense in this problem.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11029390/289396